# Creating a dictionary with same values

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have dictionary `a = {}` and I want to have it a result like this

```
value = 12
a = {'a':value,'b':value,'f':value,'h':value,'p':value}
```

and so on for many `keys:same value`. Now of course I can do it like this

```
a.update({'a':value})
a.update({'b':value})
```

and so on....
but since the value is same for all the keys, don't we have a more pythonic approach to do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use [dict comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) (python 2.7+):

```
>>> v = 12
>>> d = {k:v for k in 'abfhp'}
>>> print d
{'a': 12, 'h': 12, 'b': 12, 'p': 12, 'f': 12}
```

Comment: How would you extend this to change the value in a dict that looks like `{'a': {'b': v}, {'c': v}, {'d': v}, 'e': {'f': v}, {'g': v}}`?

Answer (score 16):

How about creating a new dictionary with the keys that you want and a default value?. Check the [fromkeys](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) method.

```
>>> value=12
>>> a=dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'f', 'h', 'p'], value)
>>> print a
{'a': 12, 'h': 12, 'b': 12, 'p': 12, 'f': 12}
```

Comment: This is ok as long as value isn't mutable. Otherwise you will be in for interesting bugs

Comment: @gnibbler: Correct, but the user said "since the value is same for all the keys"... But I understand what you mean... I've had some funky issues with things like >>> i=1
>>> [i+1]*5 (gives [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], not [2, 3, 4, 5, 6])...

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a=dict(zip('abfhp',[12]*len('abfhp')))
>>> a
{'a': 12, 'h': 12, 'b': 12, 'p': 12, 'f': 12}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = dict()
for key in keys:
    a[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

As stummjr pointed out dictionary comprehension is useful to understand and use, especially since everything in python is a dicitonary.

Another way you could consider solving this problem is by lambda function.

```
makeDict = lambda keys, values: { k:v for k, v in zip(keys, values) }
makeDict( [1,2,3], list('abc') )
['a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2]
```

Here is what makeDict looks rewritten as a regular function if this adds any clarity.

```
def makeDict(keys, values):
    return { k:v for k, v in zip(keys, values) }
```

Anyway, lambdas can be something fun to play around with, also this isn't the most robust example.  There is a potential for loss of data using zip.  Both sequences must be the same length for it to properly work.  Python will iterate through till it has pairs to match up form both sequences.  The following example the extra element in values shouldn't show up in the dictionary.

```
{ k:v for k, v in zip( list('abc'), [1,2,3,4]) }
['a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2]
```