# Reverse the one-to-one mapped dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose there is a dictionary

```
a = {'a':122,'b':123,'d':333,'e':'233'}
```

Now I want to revert it as its a one-to-one dictionary so we can do that.

What I have tried:

```
In [67]: ivd=[(v,k) for (k,v) in a.items()]

In [68]: ivd
Out[68]: [(122, 'a'), (123, 'b'), ('233', 'e'), (333, 'd')]
```

Now may be some how We can convert this `ivd` into a dictionary. My questions are

1. How to change this `ivd` into a dictionary ?
2. Is there any more pythonic solution available to do this? which I think it should be there.

Comment: If you didn't get a syntax error on the last line, ipython is horribly broken; that's certainly a syntax error in cpython.

Comment: Is it a bug in ipython or its broken for my local system only?

Comment: I just installed ipython and it gives a syntax error for what you posted.

Comment: yeah it is giving syntax error to me also now. but I can still see my previous code on shell, earlier it didn;t... weird.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use dict constructor:

```
ivd = dict((v, k) for (k, v) in a.iteritems())
```

or dict comprehension in python 2.7 or later:

```
ivd = {v: k for (k, v) in a.items()}
```

Comment: `dict([(v,k) for (k,v) in a.items()])` for Python2 before generator expressions

Comment: You made my day! I didn't know about dict comprehensions. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood properly, you're almost there:

```
>>> ivd={v:k for (k,v) in a.items()}
>>> ivd
{122: 'a', 123: 'b', 333: 'd', '233': 'e'}
```

(Credit should go to stummjr for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11977757/289011 )

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
ivd = {a[key]:key for key in a}
```

where a is your dict?  It seems much simpler.  In python, you can directly iterate over the keys of a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways how it can be done:

```
a = {"a": 122, "b": 123, "d": 333, "e": "233"}

expected = {122: "a", 123: "b", 333: "d", "233": "e"}


# Use to invert dictionaries that have unique values
inverted_dict = dict(map(reversed, a.items()))
assert inverted_dict == expected, "1st"

# Use to invert dictionaries that have unique values
inverted_dict = {value: key for key, value in a.items()}
assert inverted_dict == expected, "2nd"

print("PASSED!!!")
```